# How can set Zoom In AVCaptureDevice in Mac OS

Tags: xamarin, cocoa, avfoundation, appkit, avcapturedevice

I want to add Zoom factor in `AVcaptureDevice`. But for mac OS i didn't get any solution. in iOS we can use `videoZoomFactor` this property. but for macOS nothing any property for set zoom. can you please tell me what is solution for this problem.

i want to solution for Zoom camera using AVCaptureDevice.(AVFoundation) for mac OS.

Comment: Could this help [Manual Camera Controls in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/intro-to-manual-camera-controls)?